# TFS file name check at checkin

Tags: tfs

Im looking to incorporate a check functionality in TFS to ensure that new files which are added have a specific naming convention. Can someone provide insights on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS supports Check-in Policies.

There are set in the source control settings of each Team Project.

As well as a few included with TFS itself and more in TFS PowerToys you can create your own. You'll need the Visual Studio SDK, and information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) (information for 2005 but should be easy to adapt for later versions).

Comment: The one caveat to this is that they are *client side* policies, so once you create them, they will need to be deployed to all of your developers' machines.